# How to Partition an array into 2 arrays with equal sums

Tags: python, arrays, list

we have an array of integers that has to be partitioned into 2 arrays. My goal is not just to say it's possible or not, it has to return the 2 arrays as an output.

Input = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

output = [1, 3, 4] [2, 6]

Both the arrays need to have the same sum. In this case, it is 8 for both arrays. All the elements should be used and no integers should repeat again in the output.

This is how I am trying.

```
def partition(nums):
    if sum(nums) % 2:
        return "Not possible"
    
    target = (sum(nums))/2
    possible = set()
    possible.add(0)

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        next = set()
        for t in possible:
            next.add(t + nums[i])
            if t + nums[i] == target:
                sub = [t, nums[i]]
                print(sub)
            next.add(t)
        possible = next

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
print(partition(nums))
```

This code repeats the same elements and makes an array like [4,4]. I don't understand what to do to stop that.

I am a newbie. So you can completely rewrite it and come up with your own technique. Is it even possible to do something like that?

Comment: I want to advise against using `next` as a variable name, as it replaces a built-in functionality.

Comment: You say your input is an array: does it mean you are allowed to have repeated elements in the input? E.g. is `[1, 1]` a valid input?

Comment: First, I would calculate the sum of all digits - as you did. Then you can use itertools for suitable combinations.

Comment: @nonDucor I don't think that makes any difference for the implementation, but maybe I am missing something

Comment: Your implementation only uses `set`s, which means that it will not work with an input with repeated elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use knapsack algorithm. The knapsack has to hold a weight of Total Sum/2. Get the items whose weight is (Total Sum)/2.the remaining items will have same weight.

Other approach is backtracking. Just run through the list to get a combination of numbers summing to Total Sum/2, once found a list return. But this will be inefficient.

Comment: Thanks, the Backtracking option worked for me.